# How to open a web browser inside a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this issue has been addressed before, but I couldn't find a solution that was relevant to my project. My project is an HTML editor/interpreter that uses the `webbrowser` module to run the given HTML code on a web browser. I want to be able to open the web browser in my tkinter window instead of in the actual browser. How can I implement this in my program? Some of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)


def run_code():
    window_title = window.title()
    index = window_title.index("-") + 2
    window_title = window_title[index::]

    with open(window_title, "w") as path:
        content = text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
        path.write(content)

    basename = os.path.basename(window_title)
    new_file = open(basename, "w")
    new_file.write(content)
    new_file.close()
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("file:///" + os.getcwd() + "/" + basename)


def get_stringvar(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1] == ">") and ("<" in line):
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<") + 1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        return "break"


def file_func():
    frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    text_box.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    run_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")


create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Flux-Regular", 12), fg="black")
text_box.bind("<Tab>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Sujay, I've seen others do it, but I don't know how I can apply what they did in my project

Comment: @Roni Where did you see it?

Comment: @Sujay, I searched my question up and a few pages addressing that issue popped up. I looked in all the pages, but didn't know how to apply the solutions in my own program

Comment: @Sujay, I've found a solution. I'm gonna post it as an answer

Comment: as I know `tkinter` doesn't have good module for this. It has some module which can display `HTML` but has problem with `CSS` and it can't run `JavaScript`. It can be better to use `PyQt` instead of `tkinter`. Eventually check [CEF Python](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) for `Chromium Embedded Framework`. It seems it has [example for tkinter](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my question after some more research. My solution doesn't include opening a web browser, but it includes using the [tkhtmlview](https://pypi.org/project/tkhtmlview/) module to run the HTML code. I've also added a `Toplevel` widget to display the output on. Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)


def run_code():
    window_title = window.title()
    index = window_title.index("-") + 2
    window_title = window_title[index::]

    with open(window_title, "w") as path:
        content = text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
        path.write(content)

    basename = os.path.basename(window_title)
    new_file = open(basename, "w")
    new_file.write(content)
    new_file.close()
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window.configure(bg="white")
    window2.title("Console")
    window2.state("zoomed")
    my_label = HTMLLabel(window2, html=content)
    my_label.place(x=0, y=10)


def get_stringvar(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1] == ">") and ("<" in line):
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<") + 1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        return "break"


def file_func():
    frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    text_box.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    run_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")


create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Flux-Regular", 12), fg="black")
text_box.bind("<Tab>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

window.mainloop()
```

Edit: @TheLizzard told me that `tkhtmlview` isn't compatible with js and css, so I'm just gonna stick to the `webbrowser` module.

Comment: if you want to get data from some website, you can use sth like `html = request.get(url).text` or sth like that and then `html` willl contain all of the html of that site (don't forget to `import requests` also if you are interested here is a [tutorial by Corey Schafer about `requests`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs))

Comment: also you can't really open a web browser in your app since web browser is itself a standalone application, you can use the above method tho to get the contents of a website and display in tkinter and then you will have a web browser yourself (which kinda seems what you are going for in some way)

Comment: @Matiiss, good idea! I'm gonna check out the video, so I can learn about requests and how to implement them. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Matiiss, I have a question about requests. What if a link or an image is part of the output? Will I be able to display it on the tkinter window?

Comment: @Roni According to [this](https://pypi.org/project/tkhtmlview/), `tkhtmlview` should support images as well. Also please note that there is no JS support, so most webpages aren't going to load correctly.

Comment: @TheLizzard, is there a way to add JS support?

Comment: @Roni Only if you want to rewrite the whole of the module (which will take a lot of time). If you add JS support and expand the CSS, you will have a full web browser. Also if you are going to add JS support, you will need to look at the security aspects of it. Modern web browsers are very complex to make sure the JS on a website can't access something that it shouldn't.

Comment: @TheLizzard, should I just stick to opening the web browser with the `webbrowser` module?

Comment: @Roni Yes, use `webbrowser` if you want JS. If you aren't going to use JS, then you can choose between the `webbrowser` or the `tkhtmlview`. If I knew more about JS and HTML, I would have tried to make a proper browser that can be imbedded into `tkinter`.

Comment: @Roni I found [this](https://pypi.org/project/tkinterweb/). It is supposed to support more things than the `tkhtmlview` module. I tried it and it kind of works.

Comment: @TheLizzard, I tried `tkinterweb` , but when I click run, it outputs: `Oops. The page you've requested could not be found.`

Comment: @Roni that issue comes up half the time, so yeah, `tkinterweb` isn't that reliable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pywebview to show it insid your tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import webview
  
tk = Tk()
  
tk.geometry("800x450")
webview.create_window('Geeks for Geeks', 'index.html')
webview.start()          
tk.destroy()
```